# How to export/import the following data in a proper way?

Tags: export, import, data

Consider numeric data that has the form

```
{{{a,{b,c,d},e,f,g,h,k,{l,m,n},o}, ...},...},
```

where the first ... mean other similar rows, while the second ... mean similar structures. A toy example is

```
data={{{535, {-10.2125, -20.2039, 35.0112}, 42.1021, 7.21051, 0.573983, 
  1.22031, -2.03881, {0., 0., 0.}, 
  0}, {521, {-9.02828, -17.8807, 31.429}, 37.6437, 7.13084, 0.567418, 
  1.23246, -2.03837, {0., 0., 0.}, 
  0}, {-321, {-1.18421, -2.32325, 3.58218}, 4.45847, 9.03114, 
  0.629239, 1.12261, -2.04219, {0., 0., 0.}, 
  0}, {-421, {-3.03676, -3.47709, 6.20393}, 7.95548, 4.26567, 0.63973,
   1.10491, -2.2887, {-0.000127805, -0.000253119, 0.00044491}, 
  0.000527587}, {-11, {-0.622267, -2.0742, 3.33932}, 3.98024, 7789.12,
   0.575316, 
  1.21786, -1.86226, {-0.000127805, -0.000253119, 0.00044491}, 
  0.000527587}, {18000, {-5.36925, -12.3294, 21.8857}, 25.708, 25.708,
   0.550979, 
  1.26345, -1.98151, {-0.000127805, -0.000253119, 0.00044491}, 
  0.000527587}, {-211, {-1.3488, -1.40502, 1.29289}, 2.34223, 16.7818,
   0.984764, 
  0.622779, -2.33578, {-0.000331106, -0.000485899, 0.000860242}, 
  0.00104199}, {321, {-1.68796, -2.07207, 4.91103}, 5.61325, 11.3703, 
  0.498379, 
  1.36854, -2.25439, {-0.000331106, -0.000485899, 0.000860242}, 
  0.00104199}},{{535, {-3.08825, 1.62629, 60.6735}, 61.0522, 10.4559, 0.0574624, 
  3.5495, 2.65689, {0., 0., 0.}, 
  0}, {521, {-2.67021, 1.28728, 55.4199}, 55.7482, 10.5604, 0.0534371,
   3.62216, 2.69238, {0., 0., 0.}, 
  0}, {-321, {-0.418043, 0.339014, 5.25358}, 5.30396, 10.7438, 
  0.102094, 2.97414, 2.46021, {0., 0., 0.}, 
  0}, {-421, {-2.75151, 0.00555734, 28.1596}, 28.3544, 15.2034, 
  0.0974022, 3.02126, 
  3.13957, {-0.000223351, 0.000107675, 0.00463563}, 
  0.00464226}, {-11, {-0.786279, 0.0256629, 5.24043}, 5.29901, 
  10369.9, 0.149008, 2.59505, 
  3.10897, {-0.000223351, 0.000107675, 0.00463563}, 
  0.00464226}, {18000, {0.86758, 1.25606, 22.0199}, 22.0948, 22.0948, 
  0.0692156, 3.36328, 
  0.966329, {-0.000223351, 0.000107675, 0.00463563}, 
  0.00464226}, {-211, {-1.68904, 0.832884, 15.597}, 15.7106, 112.564, 
  0.120161, 2.81087, 2.68347, {-0.000238726, 0.000107706, 0.00479298},
   0.00480013}, {321, {-1.06247, -0.827326, 12.5626}, 12.6438, 
  25.6116, 0.106783, 
  2.92915, -2.47999, {-0.000238726, 0.000107706, 0.00479298}, 
  0.00480013}}}
```

I export it using the following command:

```
Export["dat.dat", data, "Table"]
```

When importing, the structure becomes broken:

```
dataImp=Import["dat.dat", "Table"]
```

> {{"{535,", "{-10.2125,", "-20.2039,", "35.0112},", "42.1021,",
> "7.21051,", "0.573983,", "1.22031,", "-2.03881,", "{0.,", "0.,",
> "0.},", "0}", "{521,", "{-9.02828,", "-17.8807,", "31.429},",
> "37.6437,", "7.13084,", "0.567418,", "1.23246,", "-2.03837,",
> "{0.,", "0.,", "0.},", "0}", "{-321,", "{-1.18421,", "-2.32325,",
> "3.58218},", "4.45847,", "9.03114,", "0.629239,", "1.12261,",
> "-2.04219,", "{0.,", "0.,", "0.},", "0}", "{-421,", "{-3.03676,",
> "-3.47709,", "6.20393},", "7.95548,", "4.26567,", "0.63973,",
> "1.10491,", "-2.2887,", "{-0.000127805,", "-0.000253119,",
> "0.00044491},", "0.000527587}", "{-11,", "{-0.622267,", "-2.0742,",
> "3.33932},", "3.98024,", "7789.12,", "0.575316,", "1.21786,",
> "-1.86226,", "{-0.000127805,", "-0.000253119,", "0.00044491},",
> "0.000527587}", "{18000,", "{-5.36925,", "-12.3294,", "21.8857},",
> "25.708,", "25.708,", "0.550979,", "1.26345,", "-1.98151,",
> "{-0.000127805,", "-0.000253119,", "0.00044491},", "0.000527587}",
> "{-211,", "{-1.3488,", "-1.40502,", "1.29289},", "2.34223,",
> "16.7818,", "0.984764,", "0.622779,", "-2.33578,", "{-0.000331106,",
> "-0.000485899,", "0.000860242},", "0.00104199}", "{321,",
> "{-1.68796,", "-2.07207,", "4.91103},", "5.61325,", "11.3703,",
> "0.498379,", "1.36854,", "-2.25439,", "{-0.000331106,",
> "-0.000485899,", "0.000860242},", "0.00104199}"}, {"{535,",
> "{-3.08825,", "1.62629,", "60.6735},", "61.0522,", "10.4559,",
> "0.0574624,", "3.5495,", "2.65689,", "{0.,", "0.,", "0.},", "0}",
> "{521,", "{-2.67021,", "1.28728,", "55.4199},", "55.7482,",
> "10.5604,", "0.0534371,", "3.62216,", "2.69238,", "{0.,", "0.,",
> "0.},", "0}", "{-321,", "{-0.418043,", "0.339014,", "5.25358},",
> "5.30396,", "10.7438,", "0.102094,", "2.97414,", "2.46021,", "{0.,",
> "0.,", "0.},", "0}", "{-421,", "{-2.75151,", "0.00555734,",
> "28.1596},", "28.3544,", "15.2034,", "0.0974022,", "3.02126,",
> "3.13957,", "{-0.000223351,", "0.000107675,", "0.00463563},",
> "0.00464226}", "{-11,", "{-0.786279,", "0.0256629,", "5.24043},",
> "5.29901,", "10369.9,", "0.149008,", "2.59505,", "3.10897,",
> "{-0.000223351,", "0.000107675,", "0.00463563},", "0.00464226}",
> "{18000,", "{0.86758,", "1.25606,", "22.0199},", "22.0948,",
> "22.0948,", "0.0692156,", "3.36328,", "0.966329,", "{-0.000223351,",
> "0.000107675,", "0.00463563},", "0.00464226}", "{-211,",
> "{-1.68904,", "0.832884,", "15.597},", "15.7106,", "112.564,",
> "0.120161,", "2.81087,", "2.68347,", "{-0.000238726,",
> "0.000107706,", "0.00479298},", "0.00480013}", "{321,",
> "{-1.06247,", "-0.827326,", "12.5626},", "12.6438,", "25.6116,",
> "0.106783,", "2.92915,", "-2.47999,", "{-0.000238726,",
> "0.000107706,", "0.00479298},", "0.00480013}"}}

```
dataImp[[1]][[1]]
```

> "{535,"

Could you please tell me how to fix exporting/importing such that the structure of the initial data would be untouched?

Edit. It turns out that exporting/importing in format "MX" does work.

Comment: Checking the $ExportFormats: the ".dat" is not a supported format. 
Perhaps reorganizing you data into a List of Associations is more practical.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use "Table" in `Export` and `Import` functions, i.e., if you use

`Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "teste.txt", data]`

You will get the same data when importing with

`{Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "teste.txt"]}`

That is:

`{{{535, {-10.2125, -20.2039, 35.0112}, 42.1021, 7.21051, 0.573983, 1.22031, -2.03881, {0., 0., 0.}, 0}, {521, {-9.02828, -17.8807, 31.429}, 37.6437, 7.13084, 0.567418, 1.23246, -2.03837, {0., 0., 0.}, 0}, {-321, {-1.18421, -2.32325, 3.58218}, 4.45847, 9.03114, 0.629239, 1.12261, -2.04219, {0., 0., 0.}, 0}, {-421, {-3.03676, -3.47709, 6.20393}, 7.95548, 4.26567, 0.63973, 1.10491, -2.2887, {-0.000127805, -0.000253119, 0.00044491}, 0.000527587}, {-11, {-0.622267, -2.0742, 3.33932}, 3.98024, 7789.12, 0.575316, 1.21786, -1.86226, {-0.000127805, -0.000253119, 0.00044491}, 0.000527587}, {18000, {-5.36925, -12.3294, 21.8857}, 25.708, 25.708, 0.550979, 1.26345, -1.98151, {-0.000127805, -0.000253119, 0.00044491}, 0.000527587}, {-211, {-1.3488, -1.40502, 1.29289}, 2.34223, 16.7818, 0.984764, 0.622779, -2.33578, {-0.000331106, -0.000485899, 0.000860242}, 0.00104199}, {321, {-1.68796, -2.07207, 4.91103}, 5.61325, 11.3703, 0.498379, 1.36854, -2.25439, {-0.000331106, -0.000485899, 0.000860242}, 0.00104199}}\n{{535, {-3.08825, 1.62629, 60.6735}, 61.0522, 10.4559, 0.0574624, 3.5495, 2.65689, {0., 0., 0.}, 0}, {521, {-2.67021, 1.28728, 55.4199}, 55.7482, 10.5604, 0.0534371, 3.62216, 2.69238, {0., 0., 0.}, 0}, {-321, {-0.418043, 0.339014, 5.25358}, 5.30396, 10.7438, 0.102094, 2.97414, 2.46021, {0., 0., 0.}, 0}, {-421, {-2.75151, 0.00555734, 28.1596}, 28.3544, 15.2034, 0.0974022, 3.02126, 3.13957, {-0.000223351, 0.000107675, 0.00463563}, 0.00464226}, {-11, {-0.786279, 0.0256629, 5.24043}, 5.29901, 10369.9, 0.149008, 2.59505, 3.10897, {-0.000223351, 0.000107675, 0.00463563}, 0.00464226}, {18000, {0.86758, 1.25606, 22.0199}, 22.0948, 22.0948, 0.0692156, 3.36328, 0.966329, {-0.000223351, 0.000107675, 0.00463563}, 0.00464226}, {-211, {-1.68904, 0.832884, 15.597}, 15.7106, 112.564, 0.120161, 2.81087, 2.68347, {-0.000238726, 0.000107706, 0.00479298}, 0.00480013}, {321, {-1.06247, -0.827326, 12.5626}, 12.6438, 25.6116, 0.106783, 2.92915, -2.47999, {-0.000238726, 0.000107706, 0.00479298}, 0.00480013}}}`

Comment: The method does not work, especially in the case of many blocks {}.